# Get every possible combination of numbers (fastest possible method)

Tags: javascript, performance

I am trying to get every single combination of elements into an array. Now I can use the method below, and remove the duplicates, but this way is **far to slow** for my use.

The code below would find every possible combination for 2 digits **below** 4. Now in the code I actually want to use this for, the least possible code would be 6 for loops (within each other) with the amount being 18 (rememeber this is the minimum).

The code below would execute `amount^[amount of for loops]`, or `amount^2` which in this case is 16. That means that in the code I want to use this for, it executes `18^6` times, or **34 million times**. And this is the minimum, which would get **much** higher.

After trying to run my code (with 6 foor loops in which `amount = 18`), it crashed my browser... **My question is:** Is there any faster and more efficient (**not elegant. I don't care how elegant it is**) in which my browser won't crash?

**Note:** This question is not a duplicate question. All the other questions simply ask for a way to do this, however I already have a way. I am just trying to make it more efficient and faster so that it actually works correctly.

```js
let combinations = [];
let amount = 4;

for (let a = 0; a < amount; a++) {
  for (let b = 0; b < amount; b++) {
    combinations.push(`${a}${b}`);
  }
}

console.log(combinations);
```

Below is a snippet providing a possible example for how my code would work.

```js
let possibilities = [];
let amount = 6; //Amount is set by me, so don't worry about it being incorrect

for (let a = 0; a < amount; a++) {
  for (let b = 0; b < amount; b++) {
    possibilities.push(a + b);
  }
}

possibilities = [...new Set(possibilities)]; //Removes duplicates
possibilities.sort((a, b) => b - a); //Sorts in descending order
possibilities = possibilities.slice(0, 3); //Gets top 3 values
console.log(possibilities);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192120/discussion-on-question-by-aniket-g-get-every-possible-combination-of-numbers-fa).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, as discussed in the comments, if you need top 3 values for a particular amount, you could just do something simple like below:

```js
let amount = 6;
let highest = amount - 1,second_highest = amount - 2,third_highest = amount - 3;
let possibilities = [
    highest + highest,
    highest + second_highest,
    highest + third_highest
];

console.log(possibilities);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, this isn't want I am looking for. It works in the simplified scenario that I provided for you. Except in my real code, it isn't a simple `+` operation. It's another complicated formula that produces many different results. I'm looking more for a way in which you still use the `for` loops, but just in a highly optimized method

Comment: @AniketG ok, in that case, I would need more info on what is that complicated formula?

Comment: Well let's say there's 2x2 grid. Each box would have an object that looks something like `{ value: 20; modifiers: { left: 0, right: 0, above: 33, under: 0 } }` (The 33 would be 33%, or converted to 0.33 in the formula). What that basically means is that the **value of that one box** is 20, *however* the box **above** it would be 33% more, or `value * 1.33`. (Sorry after reading it, I realize how confusing it is. I'll try to provide you with an image demonstrating it

Comment: Look at this Google Doc I just made: https://docs.google.com/document/d/19rpyFQiDm5v2n5cfgEo9dvA3XEc6hIeRJXcpNa1eKXM/edit?usp=sharing.

It provides an input and expected output for you

Comment: @AniketG This looks like a very different problem from what we are discussing. You can add this as a new question(probably deleting this one) and explaining what each key represents in the JSON for each box.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the any better solution for this, but yes there are some conditions you need to check first.

`If(amount <= 0) return 'Invalid amount, Please enter a valid amount"`

So if somebody enters a negative or zero value your loop will goes into infinite loop, and make the situation more worst.

`if(amount === 1) return '1 possible combination'`

As amount less than 1 is 0 only and combinations for 0 is 1 only, you need not to parse whole loop for 6 digits or n digits for 0 so it will get solve in complexity of 1 instead of N(no. of digits).

And for amount greater then 1 you can create manual loops, like here you created 2 loops for 2 digits, you create 6 loops for 6 digits, better create dynamic logic for this to create number of loops automatically.

You need to consider `1111`, `1112` this type of combinations as well right?
Or if only 1234, 2134, 2314 this kind of scenarios are required? This can be done in very less complexity.

For duplication you can store combinations as a key value pair. and then Object.Keys will be your combinations.

Comment: `if somebody enters a negative or zero value your loop` what? there's no `user input` even mentioned in the question- `you create 6 loops for 6 digits` he said that it "crashes his browser" for 6 loops where amount is 18 ... so, he knows to create 6 loops, it just doesn't work

Comment: @JaromandaX for example purpose he created a everything static, I'm giving him overview so in future it will be helpful for to consider all this scenarios as well, he gave a example of 2 digits, now you will say it is for 2 digits only then how it is failing for 6 digits? This simply means his amount and digits are random.

Comment: wow, you told him to do 6 nested for loops ... `I actually want to use this for, the least possible code would be 6 for loops (within each other)` ... he KNOWS how to do it, it just takes a "long time" - because he's creating permutations, then removing duplicates to make combinations - where he could just make combinations to start with

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it isn't what I am looking for. For one, `amount` is **pre-defined** by *me*, so I will make sure it follows all the conditions (sorry I should've put that in my question). And also, others were saying, I already know to create 6 loops. It just takes too long, so I want to optimize it.